# using .htaccess getting 500 internal server error

Tags: php, .htaccess, wamp

I am new in `.htaccess` i have write a .htaccess file like

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.+) index.php?url=$1 [QSA, L]
```

now i am running my url in the browswer like `localhost/my_project/`

its give me following error

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, admin@localhost and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
```

i have starts `rewrite module` in my wamp server. also check error logs there is last line is

```
HTTP/1.1" 500 535
```

Comment: Most likely `mod_rewrite` isn't enabled.

Comment: it is enabled i have checked `httpd.conf`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a space too much!

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

#Remove that space between QSA, and L
RewriteRule ^(.+) index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```